# Как вырезать все вхождения последовательности из последовательности используя Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, haskell

У меня есть образцовая и исходная последовательности. Требуется вырезать все вхождения образцовой последовательности в исходной. На выходе получаем последовательность из последовательностей. Ниже приводятся примеры:

```
splitOn "x" "axbxc" =  ["a","b","c"]

splitOn "x" "axbxcx" = ["a","b","c",""]
```

Другими словами, нужно реализовать аналог хаскелевской функции `splitOn` в C#.

Соответственно хочется найти элегантное решение данной проблемы. Можно использовать нативный подход с квадратичной сложностью, но я не могу красиво реализовать его в C# (хотелось бы более функционального решения). Может уже существует встроенная функция? гугл по этому вопросу молчит

P.S. Последовательность может содержать не только символы, но и другие объекты (для которых определена операция равно/не равно)

Comment: `string.Split('x')`?

Comment: @ixSci, а если объекты будут не только символами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для строки есть метод: [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx). Для общего случая, для коллекции, такого метода нет — нужно писать самому. Либо же воспользоваться [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io) и использовать готовый метод [Split](https://morelinq.github.io/1.x/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Split.htm)

Comment: Быстро глянул, там вроде в роли сепаратора не может выступать последовательность

Comment: @AlexAkel, там куча вариантов, включая делегаты — можно настраивать как душе угодно.